# Java MD5.stringify() Ruby equivalent

Tags: java, ruby

Tried my best and looked allover the internet but couldn't find anything. I have this java function I need to port it to Ruby but no luck.

```
public static String stringify(byte[] buf)
{
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
  for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
  {
    int h = (buf[i] & 0xF0) >> 4;
    int l = buf[i] & 0xF;
    sb.append((char)(h > 9 ? 65 + h - 10 : 48 + h));
    sb.append((char)(l > 9 ? 65 + l - 10 : 48 + l));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

any idea? I'm almost analphabet in Java.

This function called from CFML script:

```
<cfscript>
    nonceBytes = createobject("java","coldfusion.security.SecurityUtils").generateRandom(8);
    stringify = createobject("java","coldfusion.runtime.MD5").stringify(nonceBytes);
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>#stringify#</cfoutput>
```

outputs: `9C45FC098B00BD14`

Comment: Can you tell us what is it doing ?

Comment: Should output a string like these: F8877C4CD14A04BB, 464301A9616584D0 etc.

Comment: called like: MD5.stringify(nonceBytes) <- nonceBytes 8 bytes number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be doing rudimentary number to hex conversion for each character in the buffer, so if that's the case:

```
'foo'.unpack('H*')[0]
# => "666f6f"
```